# Error creating jpa repository "IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type"

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

At first, its spring-boot web app with maven and PostgreSQL db, and I'm trying to fix error of creating JPA repository. In a nutshell it's maybe don't see my Entity class, but the Entity creates successfully in database. At first @EnableJpaRepositories don't saw any repositories, but later I don't know how, it starts work. So that's a run log:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\222.3345.118\lib\idea_rt.jar=59562:C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\222.3345.118\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Gleb\Downloads\cw3\target\classes;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.22\spring-aop-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.22\spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.10.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.12\byte-buddy-1.12.12.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.6\jaxb-runtime-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.6\txw2-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.7.2\spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.7.2\spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.22\spring-orm-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.22\spring-context-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.22\spring-tx-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.22\spring-beans-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.22\spring-aspects-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.2\spring-boot-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.2\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.11\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.15.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.15.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.3\jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.3\jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.3\jackson-core-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.65\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.65\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.65\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.22\spring-web-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.22\spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.22\spring-expression-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.3.6\postgresql-42.3.6.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.5.0\checker-qual-3.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.24\lombok-1.18.24.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.22\spring-core-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.22\spring-jcl-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-configuration-processor\2.7.2\spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\com\opencsv\opencsv\5.6\opencsv-5.6.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-text\1.9\commons-text-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.4\commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-collections4\4.4\commons-collections4-4.4.jar;C:\Users\Gleb\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.23.1-GA\javassist-3.23.1-GA.jar com.example.cw3.Cw3Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

2022-10-08 15:22:11.357  INFO 14104 --- [           main] com.example.cw3.Cw3Application           : Starting Cw3Application using Java 17 on DESKTOP-91NEKQH with PID 14104 (C:\Users\Gleb\Downloads\cw3\target\classes started by Gleb in C:\Users\Gleb\Downloads\cw3)
2022-10-08 15:22:11.361  INFO 14104 --- [           main] com.example.cw3.Cw3Application           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-10-08 15:22:12.185  INFO 14104 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-10-08 15:22:12.260  INFO 14104 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 53 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-10-08 15:22:13.189  INFO 14104 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-10-08 15:22:13.208  INFO 14104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-10-08 15:22:13.208  INFO 14104 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-10-08 15:22:13.478  INFO 14104 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-10-08 15:22:13.478  INFO 14104 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2013 ms
2022-10-08 15:22:13.753  INFO 14104 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-10-08 15:22:13.832  INFO 14104 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2022-10-08 15:22:14.166  INFO 14104 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-10-08 15:22:14.343  INFO 14104 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-10-08 15:22:14.722  INFO 14104 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-10-08 15:22:14.755  INFO 14104 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2022-10-08 15:22:15.193  INFO 14104 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-10-08 15:22:15.210  INFO 14104 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-10-08 15:22:15.515  WARN 14104 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cw3Application': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileSystemStorageService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gender_trainRepository' defined in com.example.data.repositories.Gender_trainRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Cw3Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.data.models.Gender_train
2022-10-08 15:22:15.515  INFO 14104 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-10-08 15:22:15.518  INFO 14104 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-10-08 15:22:15.578  INFO 14104 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-10-08 15:22:15.581  INFO 14104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-10-08 15:22:15.602  INFO 14104 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-10-08 15:22:15.628 ERROR 14104 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cw3Application': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileSystemStorageService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gender_trainRepository' defined in com.example.data.repositories.Gender_trainRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Cw3Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.data.models.Gender_train
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at com.example.cw3.Cw3Application.main(Cw3Application.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileSystemStorageService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gender_trainRepository' defined in com.example.data.repositories.Gender_trainRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Cw3Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.data.models.Gender_train
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:520) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:673) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:329) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gender_trainRepository' defined in com.example.data.repositories.Gender_trainRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Cw3Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.data.models.Gender_train
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.data.models.Gender_train
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:233) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:182) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:165) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:325) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 46 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My Entity class:

```
package com.example.data.models;

import lombok.*;
import net.bytebuddy.utility.nullability.MaybeNull;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Data
public class Gender_train {
    @Id
    private Integer customer_id;
    @MaybeNull
    private Boolean gender;
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.example.data.repositories;


import com.example.data.models.Gender_train;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface Gender_trainRepository extends JpaRepository<Gender_train, Integer> {
}
```

And application:

```
package com.example.cw3;



import com.example.storage.services.FileSystemStorageService;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import com.example.storage.StorageProperties;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.example")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(StorageProperties.class)
@EntityScan("data.models")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.data.repositories")


public class Cw3Application implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Resource
    FileSystemStorageService storageService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Cw3Application.class, args);

    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        storageService.deleteAll();
        storageService.init();

    }

}
```

It's my project structure:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuIeY.png)

And full project on github:
https://github.com/KillerJoke623/cw3

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao it creates Entities with it. So I just changed to full and it works. Thanks a lot! But it so strange that entities work with a short one..

Comment: Need to check why it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EntityScan` shall have full package name like
`@EntityScan("com.example.data.models")`